# Lacks with transformation of Capella HTML descriptions

Tags: m2doc

Capella supports XHTML descriptions. When publishing documentation with Capella 5.1 and M2DOc 3.2.0, several of the constructs are not supported by the method `fromHTMLBodyString`

- Indented bullet lists (lists within lists)
- subscript, superscript, strikethrough

[Exemple of typical formatting in Capella](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTJhs.png)

Is that development planned in a future version?

Other question: when descriptions include images, is there any way to ensure the picture fits in the width of the page?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The **ul** and **ol** elements are not working in some cases like the one you describe here. The is a bug opened for this:

https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues/447

The **sub** and **sup** tags are not supported. I opened the following issue:

https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues/448

The **strike** tag should work see test [here](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/tree/master/tests/org.obeonetwork.m2doc.html.tests/resources/html/strike). The **s** tag is also supported.

I don't know when this work will be planned.

To make sure images fits in the page, you will have to [write a Java service](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#providing-new-services). You will need to call the [fit() service](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/blob/a0a54553bacd9e99895d01778c69d3af51669626/plugins/org.obeonetwork.m2doc/src/org/obeonetwork/m2doc/services/ImageServices.java#L214). You can have a look at this [service](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/Capella-Extensions/blob/aaa718e99b5e4df1bb121659318bc65b61fb5a34/plugins/org.obeonetwork.capella.m2doc.aql.queries/src/org/obeonetwork/capella/m2doc/aql/queries/M2DocGenServices.java#L288) from the Capella extensions for the general idea of the structure of the service.